# PHP echo does not work

Tags: php, string, printing, echo

I am trying to print a variable between curly braces as

```
Product_number{product_version}
```

I tried

```
echo "$product_number{$product_version}";
```

But that does not work. I don't understand why :(

Comment: it is not echo issue but *strings syntax*. Very important to understand that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try using double braces:

```
echo "$product_number{{$product_version}}";
```

You can also do:

```
echo "$product_number{".$product_version."}";
```

`{` followed by `$` is treated specially. It is mainly used when you want to append a string immediately at the end of a variable's value:

```
$v = 'hack';
echo "I {$v}ed it";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo $product_number . "{" . $product_version . "}";
```

Answer (score 2):

Escape the "{":

```
echo "$product_number\{$product_version}";
```

Comment: Yes, I did. I guess the problem was to avoid the use of "{}" as grouping elements in the expression. "{$product_version}" seems to give the same result as "${product_version}", which is just the contents of $product_version .